# use of iframe ajax in android browser

Tags: android, html, ajax, iframe

I have a html page which is used in a android application . From this page i need to post data to server and response is an attachment which needs to be downloaded. I used the hidden iframe hack for this purpose. But unfortunately its failing. Can anyone explain the root cause?

```
function download(){

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    //iframe.src = "http://localhost:9080/HttpOptions/MultiPartServlet";
    iframe.style.display = "none";  
    iframe.id = "myframe";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    var doc = document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.document;

    var form = doc.createElement("form"); 
    form.setAttribute("name", "theForm"); // give form a name
    form.setAttribute("id", "theForm"); // give form a name
    form.setAttribute("action", "http://localhost:9080/HttpOptions/MultiPartServlet"); // give form an action
    form.setAttribute("method", "post"); // give form a method

    var par1 = doc.createElement("input");
    par1.setAttribute("name", "theSubmit"); // give input a name
    par1.setAttribute("type", "submit"); // make it a submit button
    par1.setAttribute("value", "Submit"); // give input a value


    var par2 = doc.createElement("input");
    par2.setAttribute("name", "name"); // give input a name
    par2.setAttribute("type", "text"); // make it a submit button
    par2.setAttribute("value", "deepak"); // give input a value

    form.appendChild(par1);
    form.appendChild(par2);

    doc.body.appendChild(form);
    var myframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    form.submit();







}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `failing` ?

Comment: its showing an error saying accessing iframe is a security issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the `document.domain` to same value in both parent page and framed page.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.domain = 'example.com';
</script>
```

Put this in both parent page and framed page, and the problem will be gone.

Comment: the html is not browsed in android.it is used in an app wrapped using phonegap

Comment: still you have to deal with cross-domain issues.

Comment: iframe usage is for solving crossdomain issues instead of going for ajax call.the same piece of code is working in chrome and safari browser. The issue is seen in android browser only

Comment: Is it related to localhost path ? Mobile browsers don't like localhost much, I guess.